# Error while executing query using send attachment

Tags: sql-server-2014

when i am executing the below query, I am getting error as:-

Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.

This is my query:-

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
@profile_name = 'Mail Alerts',  
@recipients = 'v-pusah@microsoft.com',  
 @subject = 'Overlapping Subscriptions',
@body = 'kaise ho',
 @query = 'select b_id from tp_sub',
```

@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'result.txt',
@query_result_separator=',',@query_result_width =5000000,
@query_result_no_padding=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to specify the database prefix in the sql query in the @query parameter. After lot of scratch on my head i realized without prefixing DB name+Schema in Exec @query it will not work.

Did not work: @query = 'SELECT fields FROM table'
Works: @query = 'SELECT fields FROM database..table'